# Saving a TF2 keras model with custom signature defs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a Keras (sequential) model that could be saved with custom signature defs in Tensorflow 1.13 as follows:

```
from tensorflow.saved_model.utils import build_tensor_info
from tensorflow.saved_model.signature_def_utils import predict_signature_def, build_signature_def

model = Sequential() // with some layers

builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

score_signature = predict_signature_def(
    inputs={'waveform': model.input},
    outputs={'scores': model.output})

metadata = build_signature_def(
    outputs={'other_variable': build_tensor_info(tf.constant(1234, dtype=tf.int64))})

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess=sess,
      tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
      signature_def_map={'score': score_signature, 'metadata': metadata})
  builder.save()
```

Migrating the model to TF2 keras was cool :), but I can't figure out how to save the model with the same signature as above. Should I be using the new `tf.saved_model.save()` or `tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model()`? How should the above code be written in TF2?

Key requirements:

- The model has a score signature and a metadata signature
- The metadata signature contains 1 or more constants

Answer (score 16):

The solution is to create a `tf.Module` with functions for each signature definition:

```py
class MyModule(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, model, other_variable):
    self.model = model
    self._other_variable = other_variable

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 1), dtype=tf.float32)])
  def score(self, waveform):
    result = self.model(waveform)
    return { "scores": results }

  @tf.function(input_signature=[])
  def metadata(self):
    return { "other_variable": self._other_variable }
```

And then save the module (not the model):

```py
module = MyModule(model, 1234)
tf.saved_model.save(module, export_path, signatures={ "score": module.score, "metadata": module.metadata })
```

Tested with Keras model on TF2.

Comment: Extremely helpful answer! I scoured the internet for a while before finding it.

Also of interest: I tested it out, and you don't even need to wrap in a tf.Module for a custom Keras Model subclass. You can just add the metadata function as you've written it and everything works, along with tf.keras.models.save/load

Wrote up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642590/add-metadata-to-tensorflow-frozen-graph-pb

Comment: I am training a text classification model in tf2. I am using python logic to build up vocab dicts, i.e. item2idx and idx2item which are present in a dataset class object. I tried and failed to export that as the other_variable in place of simple 1234 that you used. Any idea what might be the issue here?